# Android - getting touch event position after using setFixedSize()

Tags: android

I have an OpenGL app which needs to run in a set screen size (800x480 in this instance).
I use the command:

```
 this.getHolder().setFixedSize(800, 480)
```

in my GLSurfaceView constructor to do this.  This means that on devices with larger screens, my app still takes up the whole screen.

My this has the consequence that in the views onTouchEvent(), the getX() & getY() methods no longer return a value scaled from (0,0) to (800,480).

I tried applying a scale factor based on the true screen size to the getX() values, but have been unable to exactly determine what it should be.

How would I scale getX() & getY()?  Is there a different method I should be using to scale the screen to my desired resolution in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've answered my own question here.
After more investigation, getting the window size with:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int w = display.getWidth();
int h = display.getHeight();
```

and using it to scale the getX(), getY() output does work; I just need to ignore the apparently incorrect values display.getWidth() returns.